# Persisting S3 using "raw" format is a good idea or not?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to S3 and thinking of persist some data into it using java.
Right now, our application consists of two services, service1 and service2.

Service1 will persist intermediate results into S3 and service2 will pick up from there and continue on.

For service1's output, I would categorize it to two categories.

1. data that other team will use and manipulate it.
2. intermediate result that is only for service2 to leverage. So no other team involved or manipulate it.

For data in category 1, I will store it using parquet file and upload to s3.
For data in category 2, I am thinking of directly save the "raw" data into a file on s3 (e.g. a map of complicated objects), cause the data structure is really complicated.

I have three questions now for saving "raw" data into S3.

1. is it a good idea? If no, why? And what is the good option? I am using java.
2. if there is nothing wrong with saving "raw" data, will I be able to get it as original when I read it back?
3. if I simply use aws S3 api to upload the object, when the data is too big, will there be a potential issue?

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon S3 is an excellent service for sharing data between processes because:

- There is no limit to the amount of storage
- There are fine-grained security controls
- S3 can 'trigger' processes when data is uploaded
- S3 supports 'ranged retrieval', so you can retrieve portions of a file. This is very handy when reading Parquet file format.
- Many tools and services can directly read from S3, such as Amazon Athena that can query data directly from S3, even in compressed and Parquet format.

Whatever you store in S3 will be exactly what you get back.

A common architecture when having two systems communicate is:

- Store the data in S3
- Send a message to the second application, pointing to the location of the data in S3 -- you might do this by sending a message to an **Amazon SQS queue**
- The second application retrieves the message from the queue, retrieves the data from S3 and processess the data.

Answer (score 2):

S3 doesn't care if your data is 'raw' or in some structured format - I store both types for different reasons and have never had a problem.

If you are concerned, run some verifications - i.e. upload files in whatever format you want, and then make sure you can consume them as you need to - but I don't think you are going to have any issues.